# node-cron not executing script on interval only console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, node-cron

On initial run, it'll run app.js however, on interval it skips over it. What might I be doing wrong here?

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', function(){
    var shell = require('./app.js');
     commandList = [
        "node app.js"
        ]

        console.log('Bot successfully executed'); 

});
```

Log:

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ node forever.js
Bot successfully executed
You have already retweeted this Tweet.
You have already retweeted this Tweet.
Bot successfully executed
Bot successfully executed
Bot successfully executed
Bot successfully executed
Bot successfully executed
Bot successfully executed
Bot successfully executed
Bot successfully executed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your `app.js` executes the code immediately, so it is executed only by requiring it (and require is cached, so it is executed only once).

You should return function from your `app.js` instead and call that on every run.

```
// app.js
module.exports = () => { 
    // your original code here
};

// forever.js
var cron = require('node-cron');
var shell = require('./app.js');

cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', function(){
    shell();

    console.log('Bot successfully executed');
});
```

Or maybe you could clear the `require` cache before running:

`delete require.cache[require.resolve('./app.js')]`

Comment: That did the trick. What ultimately allowed this to work? I tried a simple return with no luck.

Comment: You mean `return` from `app.js`, without the `module.exports` part?

Comment: Well this solution works because you return a function when you require `app.js`, not executing the code. Then you can call that function multiple times. `module.exports` part is how node modules work (what you assign to that will be exported = returned from `require()` call)

Comment: Ohhhh I see what you're saying. Thanks for the help! I sat here fighting for a good 45 minutes, should have asked a bit sooner.